# Sonos - The information returned under "information" on the Now Playing Screen should be under "On Now"

Tags: sonos

The Sonos team asked me to ask this question here on StackOverflow.

I do not know what to change in my code in order to fix the following issue.

The internal Jira (CP-2805) says:

The information returned under "information" on the Now Playing Screen should be under "On Now"

Repro: 
1. Open app in the Sonos controller 
2. Play any station

Results: 
Observe that information about what is currently playing is being returned under "information."

Expect: 
This information should be returned under "On Now."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it  is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. While a vendor may direct support questions here, those questions must meet the same requirements as any other question here - they must be on-topic for the site.

Comment: I've seen that different radio stations seem to behave differently with respect to what is shown "On Now" vs. "Information". Is your station a Shoutcast stream? If so, are you embedding StreamTitle metadata in the radio stream?

Comment: Hey @RonKuper! Yes it's Icecast / Shoutcast and we're embedding StreamTitle metadata in the stream.

Answer (score 1):

The "On Now" field on the Now Playing screen is populated by adding a `<currentShow>`node within the `<streamMetadata>` you return in your getMetadataResponse. A good example of how you might use this node can be found on the [getMetadata reference page](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/83) within Sonos Labs.

Within that documentation you will see a section called "Sample Response (Streams)". The xml example includes the use of the `<currentShow>` node. You can use this node to display the DJ that is currently on, or the title of the show that is currently playing (ex. "Fresh Air") within "On Now." The information on the currently playing track will continue to be shown within "Information" field on the Now Playing screen. If there is not a specific DJ or Show, you can omit the  node from the streamMetadata and "On Now" will remain blank.